# WinSCP and PuttyGen fail on conversion of openSSH private key to PEM or PPK formtype on windows

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, winscp, oracle-linux

I’ve generated a Linux Instance in the Oracle Cloud. Locally I work on Windows-10 Client computer. During generation of the Linux Instance Private and Open-SSH public keys have been generated in Linux and been downloaded to local windows, too.
With this now

1.) Private keys in Open-SSH format are stored on both windows and linux and kept secret

2.) I can login from into Linux using the public key with this

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command ssh -i D:\wrk\ssh-key-2020-08-01.key opc@xxx.xx.xx.xxx.
Connection is established, thus key validation is successful.
```

Now  I need a SFTP GUI Client on window for file exchange.

I tried WinSCP or Filezilla. Both tool require the privat key either in PPK or PEM format. The private key file provided by OCI/oracle [*always free version*, thus no support from oracles side to be expected] has .KEY file extension and has openSSH format, guess it's SSH2.

```
<edit added in response to comment of  Martin Prikryl>
```

Actually WinSCP does try to handle my private openSSH Keyfile by offering to convert it to Putty format. Trying to convert WinScp then signals an error: "unrecogniszed key type". Anyhow my openSSH Pub/key-keypair has proven to work with a key-exchange over a SSH-Console connection.

```
</edit added in response to comment of  Martin Prikryl>
```

Need to work on the existing private key, because I don't see a way to exchange any files between the Clound/Linux and my local Client/Windows-10. Thus I can't transfer any newly created secret private key files in PEM or PPK-Format from linux to windows or vice versa, without a FSTP connection.

**Thus my question**

How can I convert the openSSH private key in windows into PEM or PPK Format - when I get the error "unrecognised key type" while trying to do so with WinSCP?

**additional info**
Trying to come close to the request of @Martin Prikryl:

I created another LINUX instance with its own SSL-keypair and publish this here. The instance will be disposed later, thus I guess there is no need for privacy of this instance.

powershell>openssl rsa -check -in ssh-key-trial.key RSA key ok writing RSA key

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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    
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

rsa -check on the original private keyfile says it's ok. WinScp, Putty and PuttyGen nevertheless don't accept it. Hope this supports my case.

@ Martin Prikryl

Yes, I just copied the output of the above <openssl rsa -check..>-command into the text compound above. Below you see the content of the original file ssh-key-trial.key.

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

As I just found out now -File is a decrypted version of -File. My problem is/was that WinScp and PuttyGen can't handle the encrypted form of the file. <openssl rsa -check..>-command can decrypte the input and writes the decrypted version to the output.

This command decryptes the private key directly into the outputfile:

```
openssl  rsa -in ssh-key-trial.key -out decrypted_ssh-key-trial.key
```

Using this file now with WinScp I get a connection the the Oracle Infrastructure Instance. **Problem solved**.

Problem cause is:
WinSCP and PuttyGen fail on conversion of openSSH private key (encrypted form)  to PEM or PPK formtype on windows.
Solution: openSSH private key has to be decrypted first by SSH-Tool of windows-10.

WinScp, PuttyGen can't read open SSH in encrypted form, aka with fileheader `<RSA PRIVATE KEY>`

thus solution is:
decrypte the file to the form  as show above. This format is understood by WinScp 5.17.7 (Build 10640), PuttyGen Rel 0.73

Thanks to @Martin Prikryl for your support in this desperate situation, which helped me to come to an end with this.

Comment: WinSCP will [convert the key automatically to PPK format](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication#private_key), if you select PEM key. I believe FileZilla does the same.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your hint. WinSCP effectively detects my privat-keyfile to be OpenSSH and offers to convert it to PPK/Putty Format. When I let it try to do this, I get an error instead successfull conversion. The error message: unrecognised key type.I add this information to my question, to be more specific about the situation that causes the error.

Comment: for better formatting I posted my reply below

Comment: If the first line of the key file is `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, PuTTYgen (nor WinSCP) won't give you *"unrecognised key type"*.

Comment: If I take the key that you have just added to your question, paste it as it is to a text file, I can load it to the latest version of PuTTYgen or WinSCP without any problem.

Comment: Just a wild guess – Do you also copy the key from PowerShell console and paste it to a text file? Into a Notepad or similar? Notepad saves the file with UTF-8 BOM by default. PuTTYgen cannot handle that. Make sure there's no BOM. Or simply use `-out ssh-key-trial.pem` parameter instead of copy and paste.

Comment: I do not understand your solution. Once again, I can load your `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` key without any problem. What where you doing differently that it was not working for you?

Comment: So you were loading the `ssh-key-trial.key` (with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`), not the `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, right?

Comment: The private key downloaded from Oracle/OCI is in the form -----END PRIVATE KEY-----.  This file can not be interpreted by WinSCM nor by PuTTYgen. The ----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- version was first generated just by accident. I checked the original file with <openssl rsa -check>, which generated the target/solution. You check that, and didn't state any problem. Try the other original file, you should be able to reproduce my initial problem. For me it was not obvious that the original format has to be decrypted, before it can be read by WinScm, moreover both version are not human readable.

Comment: the first key block shows the solution. the second one the problem. You asked me to show the problematic key block. By accident I feel onto the solution key block, while trying to show you the problematic keyblock. Hope this helps you to rewind the confusing flow of events.

Comment: >>So you were loading the ssh-key-trial.key (with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----), not the -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----, right?
yes, and it was by no means obvious, that I have to mingle that before by interoperation, before it's understood by WinScp. But now it works and I'm happy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PuTTY Key Generator says "Couldn't load private key (not a private key)" when loading a PEM file](https://superuser.com/questions/904998/putty-key-generator-says-couldnt-load-private-key-not-a-private-key-when-lo)

Comment: No this doesn't answer the question. The answer is all low tech-level, and it answers a diffrent question, though both question are based a problems with a common ground. The answer does not mention the fact that a openSHH privat key can be decrypted and encrypted form, and that on of the most frequent failure to read/convert an OpenSHH private key file is:

Comment: There's no encrypted/decrypted form. It's just a different format of the key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Generated ssh keys using rsa, 2048 and git bash.Using PuttyKey Gen to convert failed.
I then downloaded the latest version and it worked.
Version 0.74 according to help / about.

There is new functionality even though  I've been using the same format for several years. Possibly Windows Git Bash uses new openssh or a newer process.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert OpenSSH keys to PuTTY keys using a program called `puttygen.exe`. You can download the file under **Alternative Binary Files** at this webpage: [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)

## Convert an OpenSSH key to a PuTTY key using `puttygen.exe`

- Open `puttygen.exe` and click the **Conversions** menu item on the top menu bar. Then press **Import Key**
- Navigate to the location of your OpenSSH key then click the open button.
- If a passphrase is needed for this key, you can now enter the passphrase into both of the boxes labeled `Key passphrase` and `Confirm passphrase`
- You can now save the PuTTY versions of private and/or public keys by clicking the **Save public key** and **Save private key** buttons.

[image]

Comment: OP does not seem to have the key in a format that is recognised by PuTTYgen (as WinSCP failed to convert the key and WinSCP uses PuTTYgen code for the conversion).

Comment: If I do this as described, I get:  PuTTYgen error: Couln't load private key (unrecognised key type). Thus I'm still stuck.